# SQL 2008 OPENXML ,unable to parse NTEXT data

Tags: sql-server-2008, openxml

Hi i have an xml string

```
DECLARE @XmlQue     NTEXT

SET @XmlQue='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Template TId="1">
       <QueInfo QId="1" QDetails="Are you " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/>
       <QueInfo QId="2" QDetails=" राज्य " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/>
     </Template>'
```

i want to insert the data in a table having NTEXT data type in some columns

i have written the following insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO ExpertSystem_Master 
    SELECT QIdx,@TemplateId,QDetailsx,IsYesx,IsNox,Eligibleyesx,Eligiblenox,0,0
    FROM 
    OPENXML(@XmlHdl,'/Template/QueInfo',1)
    WITH
    (    QIdx           INT '@QId',
         QDetailsx      Ntext '@QDetails',
         IsYesx         Ntext  '@IsYes', 
         IsNox          Ntext  '@IsNo', 
         Eligibleyesx   CHAR(1) '@Eligibleyes',
         Eligiblenox    CHAR(1) '@Eligibleno'   
    )
```

The data is inserted in the table but the issue is instead of setting **" राज्य"** ,the data is inserted as **"?????"**

when i try to insert the data directly it is inserted properly,the issue is while parsing it with OPENXML.

can any one help?? am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put an N before your text.. example:

```
SET @XmlQue=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Template TId="1"> 
       <QueInfo QId="1" QDetails="Are you " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/> 
       <QueInfo QId="2" QDetails=" राज्य " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/> 
     </Template>'
```

Comment: Thanks,bt d issue i am facing is i am sending the xml string as a parameter to a stored procedure.
If i per concatenate **"N"** to the parameter **@XmlQue** and pass it to the procedure it throws an error.
if i do it like this in the stored procedure
    SET @XmlQue=N''+@XmlQue
it does not work 
the only way in which is works when i write

SET @XmlQue=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Template TId="1">
       <QueInfo QId="2" QDetails=" राज्य " IsYes="Yes" IsNo="No" Eligibleyes="Y" Eligibleno="N"/> 
     </Template>'
how can i append **"N"** with the variable @XmlQue
please help???

Comment: Please mark this one as answered and open a new question. In the new question, please give more details, such as the code you are using to pass the string to the stored proc. That would help.  :)